# How do you wrestle the DRY principle with configs?

Tags: code-reuse, anti-patterns, dry

For instance, lets say we have an nginx config pointing at foo1, foo2, and foo3, as well as a haproxy config pointing at foo1, foo2, and foo3, and finally, a deployment tool pointing at the same respective servers.

How does one reconcile this?  Build some sort of configuration generator for nginx and haproxy based on the hosts?  It seems as though this would make grepping difficult and potentially hinder readability of the configuration files in general.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the only config that I'm going to be interested in is the one I'm currently looking at.  Unless the two systems are intimately tied together, it's two diffrrent configs, and it doesn't matter that they are pointing to the same group of servers.

If it's essentially the same system, then naturally it's the same config. Consolidation of the settings becomes possible, provided there are no backward compatibility concerns.